# material-ui <Grid item> component's children with 100% width overlaps parent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

When I have a full width children in a Grid item, the children overlaps to the right side of its parent.

I have reproduced the code with the problem I'm having.
https://codesandbox.io/s/rn88r5jmn

```css
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Paper, Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Grid container spacing={16}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Button variant="raised" fullWidth className={classes.button}>
              asdf
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Button variant="raised" fullWidth className={classes.button}>
              asdf
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  }
});
export default withStyles(styles)(Demo);
```

Gives me the result below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the fullWidth prop, but the margin you are setting to the buttons, you can do something like this instead:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nnxl20l2q0

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Paper, Grid, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid container spacing={16}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Button variant="raised" fullWidth>
              asdf
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Button variant="raised" fullWidth>
              asdf
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
const styles = theme => ({
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit
  }
});
export default withStyles(styles)(Demo);
```

Comment: I see. I didn't know that 100% width doesn't include the margin.

Comment: margin goes outside of the element, padding would be inside. So by adding the padding style to the parent object, you more or less achieve the same thing without adding extra width